# How do I make PHP's `exit("reason")` return a exit code that is not `0`

Tags: php, exit

I've usually coded my PHP `exit()`'s with a reason (i.e. `exit("You are not authorised to access this page");`), but I've only recently noticed that this sends the exit code `0`.

How can I made `exit` send the exit code of 1 or greater whilst still sending down a reason, yet avoid the use of the following psuedo code.

```
<?php
if ($user->isAdmin() !== true) {
     echo "You are not authorised to access this page.";
     exit(1);
}
```

Code to reproduce this problem; although it may not really be necessary. (In CLI, but the same happens on a webpage)

```
zarthus@zarth:~$ php -r "exit(1);"
zarthus@zarth:~$ echo $?
1
zarthus@zarth:~$ php -r "exit('a reason');"
zarthus@zarth:~$ echo $?
0
```

The reason I want to do this is because when I use `exit` it usually means the program has entered a stage where it needed to kill itself because something went wrong, or wasn't authorised. I'd like to use this for monitoring purposes to see if a script fully completed.

Comment: Instead of exiting with code, `throw new \Exception("With your custom comment");`

Comment: Whilst this works; it doesn't display the message to the user unless I put it in a `try{} catch(Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }` - Is there a shorter method for this? Because it seems like the example in my original post would be shorter, and more readable.

Comment: It is good practice to wrap your main script method into try block `try { doAll() } catch(Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); exit(1);}`

Comment: I'm really not sure if it is, @Erbureth

Comment: Why not? You can even get [full backtrace](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/exception.gettraceasstring.php) and debug what went wrong.

Comment: If so, you might also want to create an error handler that converts PHP Errors to exceptions. Then you have a realy clean error structure. But I think we are starting to derail this question...

Comment: If it's a good answer, then please add it as an answer and not as a comment on the question. Then the community can vote for or against it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php):

> If status is a string, this function prints the status just before exiting.
>
> If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status
>   and not printed. Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254, the
>   exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The status 0
>   is used to terminate the program successfully.

So the only option is to write your own exit function:

```
function myExit($reason, $errorcode=1) {
  if(defined("STDIN")) {
    file_put_contents('php://stderr', $reason);
  } else {
    echo $reason;
  }
  exit($errorcode);
}
```

Comment: I'll wait around a bit and see what others have to say, that does seem to be the solution thus far though.

Comment: To comply with typical console programs, you could also write to stderr instead of the echo: `file_put_contents('php://stderr', 'This text goes to STDERR');`

Comment: @ToBe, the way I've set it up is that it runs as normal webpage, but I'm also running it from command line to check the exit code. I don't think that'll work for normal webpages (but I haven't researched it yet.)

Comment: This might be usefull then: `if(defined("STDIN")) echo "we are consoleros!";`

Comment: I was unaware of that; thanks! To stay on topic: I'm looking to see what becomes of the the `exception` comments on the original post. It really sounds like an edgy case to me. But if I can find nothing sourced on it being common good practise; I'll accept this as answer in a bit (since there really aren't any other answers). Seems like it's still getting some attention for now though!